# Need to mount my single Ubuntu 16.04 partition with the mount 'suid' option enabled

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, mount, system

I'm running an ubuntu 16.04 LTS system on a single partition (i.e., the entire system resides on the `/dev/sda1` partition of my hard drive).  It is automatically mounted (of course) at boot up and mount shows it mounted with the following options:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
```

My problem is that I've written a small tool for my local system (in C++) which I've placed in the `/usr/local/sbin` directory that I need for it to run as root for it to correctly fulfill its task. I have set its setuid bit but it still does not run as root as I need it to.  I did some searching and found that if a partition is not mounted with the mount `suid` option, even if an application has its suid bit set, it will not run as root.  I looked at the partition's entry in the `/etc/fstab` file to see what options it has for it to be mounted and found the following entry for it:

```
UUID=04c08145-f454-4562-8212-3e7726b97d34 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

Can someone tell me what I need to change in this entry so that this system partition is mounted with the mount `suid` option enabled?

Comment: AFAIK the default options include `suid` (at least for ext4 filesystems) and I don't believe your system would function properly if `/` were not already mounted `suid` (things like `sudo` would break) - what makes you think it isn't? How exactly did you test your tool?

Comment: I guess I'm wrong.  See my reply to the answer below for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Your deduction that not mounting with the "suid" option is not correct.  This is actually the default, unless you specify "nosuid" to negate it (refer to http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/mount.8.html)

We can also generally know that it is working fine, because setuid is used by many system tools, even ping! su and sudo would not work unless setuid was working.

Most likely your setuid is somehow setup wrong, my first guess would be that your binary is not owned by root.  The output of "ls -la /usr/local/sbin/BINARY" would help understand the current status of the binary.  You could compare the output to sudo, which is correctly setuid:

```
$ ls -lad /usr/bin/sudo
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 140944 Jan 14 07:41 /usr/bin/sudo
```

Finally it's also possible whatever context you are executing the application is forbidden to use this setuid binary by an AppArmor profile.

Comment: I looked at the permissions of the tool and the permissions look fine. Maybe I'm wrong about another assumption:  My tool is designed to be run by a mount command triggered from an entry in /etc/fstab.  My tool uses 'su' to run a command as the user who issued the mount command (though I assume that the tool runs as root).  What I thought would happen is that, since the tool is running as root, the 'su' command would run the command as the user *without requiring the user's password*. My goal is to not require a password for the user running the mount command.  Is this possible?

Comment: mount itself is setuid, so something triggered by a mount would likely run as root.  Running simply "su" will not drop back to the non-root user, you'd have to specify the username in some way - are you doing that? I'd suggest posting your entire solution for review with details of exactly what you are trying to do and source for your tool, etc.

Comment: How do I post my entire solution for review?  This is my first post, and I don't know how to do that. Can you please tell me how? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe I can refer you to a post I started on this same problem on stackoverflow.com that is detailed as to what I'm trying to achieve and then maybe you might have a suggestion for me.  Here's the link to the post I started earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43313238/removing-su-password-request-from-within-a-c-program